# Hypothesis test for proportion falling below a threshold

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, range

Let's assume the following Null and Alternative hypothesis of a proportion:

- `H0`: $p < 0.01$
- `H1`: $p \geq 0.01$

Generally, in all various hypothesis testing literature, I see equality condition being used for `H0`. **I wonder how I can think about this scenario? and what the test statistics will look like?**

Comment: A hypothesis test is constructed for possible rejection of the null hypothesis $H_0$. That's why all the terminologies, Type-I error, p-values are defined that way. The equality sign gives you the opportunity to find a distribution of the test statistic. Having the equality sign under $H_1$ will not change how you construct the test statistic, however, you have to redefine all the terminologies accordingly, which will not be very helpful.

Comment: You have to remember, hypothesis testing revolves around rejecting or not rejecting the $H_0$, constructing the test statistic under $H_1$ might jeopardise that very notion. The whole testing procedure will have to be redefined.

Comment: The purpose of $H_1$ is to tell you what counts as an extreme result when looking at the data assuming $H_0$ is correct.  Since $p=0.009$ and $p=0.009999$ etc. are part of $H_0$, having $p=0.01$ is no more likely to produce extreme results than $\sup(p): p \in H_0$

Comment: @Henry, I agree that $sup(p): p \in H_0$ will be very similar to the $p=0.01$ of the $H_1$. However, one can say the same thing about the generic equality-based $H_0$ tests (e.g. $H_0: p = 0.01$ and $H_1: p > 0.01$). So, I think it would be proper if I can construct the distribution of $p$ under the $H_0$. Surely, it is more difficult of a construction, but I can use simulations to construct the distribution empirically, no?

Comment: The point is that you are testing under $H_0$ while $H_1$ is say "high values count as extreme, low values do not" you reject what would be the top $5\%$ or whatever of the distribution if $H_0$ was correct.  If it makes no practical difference to the critical region whether you assume $p=0.00999999$  or $p=0.01$ then in effect you are saying $p=0.01$ is part of $H_0$.

Comment: @Henry, I think I know what you referring to (just where the equality sign lies). I don't think that it's important for me. I can easily do: $H_0: p \geq 0.01$ and $H_1: p < 0.01$). Now, having thought about the concepts, I think I can take the extreme case of the Null Hypothesis that makes the "*rejection of the null* more difficult. In such a setting, if I end up rejecting the Null, the Type I error rate can be known (a conservative upper bound). Therefore, I can simply change the Null to be: $H_0: p=0.01$ and have the same alternative $H_1: p<0.01$.